# Why the method valueOf(String name) of enum is not defined in the abstract class java.lang.Enum?

Tags: java, enums

In core Java, the abstract class `java.lang.Enum` is the base class of all Java enumeration types. There are some common methods such as:

- `public final String name()`
- `public final int ordinal()`
- `public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`

However, as we all know, there is also a frequently used method `public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(String name)`, which doesn't appear in the Java API docs - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html - at all. Anyone can explain this?

Comment: Well, for a start, type erasure means that such a method would have no way of knowing what type to return.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth But the `Enum<T>> T valueOf(String name)` indeed can work without issue

Comment: not in that form, but a non-static version, delegating to the static method might be useful.

Comment: That works because it's compiler-generated magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were such a method `public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(String name)` on `Enum`, the implementation would have no way of knowing the concrete type to be returned, due to [*type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  So it has to be implemented on each concrete sub-class.

In practice, this is done via compiler-generated "magic".  Or as the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3) puts it, as an "implicitly declared method".

Comment: Made a revision on this problem and found that this is not checked. @Oliver Charlesworth thanks a lot for the explanation :)